# SQL Table structure for historical of more than single kind of process

Tags: mysql, sql

Not sure if it will be having a use or not. I have a table that contains history data for order progress, and a table that contains history data for a ticket

```
---------------+
order_progress |
---------------+
id (UUID)      |
order_id       | 
status         |
---------------+

----------------+
ticket_progress |
----------------+
id (UUID)       |
ticket_id       |
status          |
----------------+
```

is it possible if we merge that 2 tables of historical data into one table?

```
--------------+
progress      |
--------------+
id            |
ref           |
status        |
--------------+
```

The ref record used for relationship to the other 2 tables `order_progress.id` and `ticket_progress.id` act like foreign key. Is there a better solution for this case? Or will it cause a problem in the future? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you can try to use `UNION` or `UNOIN ALL` to combine two table to be a result set.

```
SELECT id,order_id ref,status FROM order_progress 
UNION ALL
SELECT id,ticket_id,status FROM ticket_progress
```

> use `UNION` will remove rows when that row displays as same on `order_progress` and `ticket_progress`.

**Edit**

If you have more types of historical data (order, ticket, job, app, etc.. progress).

can we just use a single table to store every historical data?

You can try to use a flag column to represent table types

Here is a sample for you

```
---------------+
progress       |
---------------+
id (UUID)      |
order_id       | 
status         |
Type           |
---------------+
```

Here is some map type of tables

- order = 1
- ticket = 2
- job = 3

If you want to get `job` information you can try to this query.

```
SELECT * FROM progress WHERE type = 3
```

OK, I see, Maybe you can consider using `Denormalization` to your table if you want to combine `id` from different types of rows.

```
---------------+
progress       |
---------------+
id (UUID)      |
order_id       |
ticket_id      | 
job_id         |
order_status   |      
ticket_status  |      
job_status     |      
---------------+
```

Comment: ok for the query to show a union data. And its ok if we only have 2 type of historical data (order and ticket progress). But what if we have more than we can anticipate in the first place, just said like 8 type of historical data (order, ticket, job, app, etc.. progress) so we have 8 almost identical tables? can we just use a single table to store every historical data?

Comment: @far1023 I had edit my question hope that help you

Comment: how do we set up constraint properties in table `progress`? because the foreign is no longer refer to a field in one table.

Comment: @far1023 I edit my answer